# I want to edit the type selection list in the file upload window

Tags: html, file, internet-explorer, input, upload

If I open the file upload window without specifying the accept attribute, it will accept all files.
However, an option list is created so that you can select another type.

The first attachment is the pre-requested file. The second attachment is what i want.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi kwan, can you post the markup for your file upload control and the mime-type of the file you want to allow your users to select. eg. <input type="file" accept="????"/>.

Comment: I did wrote just <input type="file" multiple/>

Comment: here is a link to the mdn documentation with examples of using the accept attribute for different file extensions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: I approve all files.
In IE, however, a list of other extensions is shown for the file type.
Chrome is not.
Chrome and ie are different. Why?

Comment: Please provide some code with your questions so that we can test it ourselves.... Development Improvements for IE has concluded with the HTML5 working standard. A workaround would be to use a validation method and only accept the file types that you want... see the examples in the MDN document link provided.

Comment: <quote>I approve all files. In IE, however, a list of other extensions is shown for the file type. Chrome is not. Chrome and ie are different. Why?</quote>Yes.... that is a known bug...